# Getting a Bootstrap Modal to open when Asp.net Drop Down List Item Selected

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, modal-dialog

So my issue is that I have an `Asp.net` Drop Down List control with a listing of names, and the last option opening a modal when selected to add new name. I currently show and hide a div, but I am converting my app to bootstrap and I can't seem to get the bootstrap modal to work as I'd like.

Currently my modal div is as follows:

```
<asp:Panel ID="AddPOCPanel" runat="server" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">...</asp:Panel>
```

And in my code-behind, when I populate my drop down list I add the necessary attributes per the bootstrap api:

```
var add = new ListItem("Add Point of Contact");
add.Attributes.Add("data-toggle","modal");
add.Attributes.Add("data-target","#AddPOCPanel");
```

Here's the signature of my `DropDownList`:

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="POC1DropDownList" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" class="form-control" OnSelectedIndexChanged="POCDropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged">
                            </asp:DropDownList>
```

I've tried a number of things and made some observations:

- This seems to be unique to the "option" element, in that if I try to use a link or button in place of the dropdown option, it works just fine. So is an option's behavoir not allow  me to do what I am attempting?
- I am using `AutoPastBack="true"`, which "overrides" the modal, but removing this has no effect.

Comment: Please do not use "bootstrap" tag, use "twitter-bootstrap" since it means something else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I was making it more difficult on myself than necessary, instead of manipulating the DropDownList option for "Add Point of Contact" I did the following:

When the user selects the last option to add a contact, I looked at the value selected in my postback (note that I am using AutoPostBack="true"), and if it was the "Add Point of Contact" option then I did the following:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "ShowModal", "$('#AddPOCPanel').modal('show'); $('#MainContent_POC1DropDownList').val('');", false);
```

This is a great solution, as it works with behavoir of webforms well, for example if using validators, you can do the following:

```
protected void SomeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Page.IsValid)
    {
        //Do work then...
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "HideModal", "$('#AddPOCPanel').modal('hide'); $('#MainContent_POC1DropDownList').val('');", true);
    }
    else
    {
        //Make sure modal stays open...
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "ShowModal", "$('#AddPOCPanel').modal('show'); $('#MainContent_POC1DropDownList').val('');", true);
    }
```

So hopefully this helps anyone finding themselves in the same bind down the road...